# How to use netcat inside a gitlab-ci.yml

Tags: gitlab-ci, netcat

I try to inspect that a service is up inside a gitlab runner.

For that I use `netcat` in my `.gitlab-ci.yml`

```
image: python:latest

before_script:
  - apt-get update -yq
  - apt-get install -y python-dev python-pip tree
  ## check about Rabbit
  - apt-get install -y curl netcat
  - nc -v -zw3 rabbitmq 15672
```

but when I run I get this error::

```
Unpacking netcat (1.10-41) ...
Setting up netcat-traditional (1.10-41) ...
update-alternatives: using /bin/nc.traditional to provide /bin/nc (nc) in auto mode
Setting up netcat (1.10-41) ...
$ nc -zw3 rabbitmq 15672
$ nc -v -zw3 rabbitmq 15672
rabbitmq [172.17.0.2] 15672 (?) : Connection refused
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: netcat is probably working alright, it justs spits out a non-zero error code if it cannot connect to a given host on a given port. So maybe you should merge this question with your other question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409988/how-to-use-rabbit-inside-a-gitlab-ci-yml-file and mention that you've tried this netcat command and it's not working properly.

Comment: Try running `netcat`with the `-v` option for a more verbose output: `nc -zw3 -v rabbitmq 15672`

Comment: effectively this is related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409988/how-to-use-rabbit-inside-a-gitlab-ci-yml-file

Comment: I've updated the run with netcat -v on the issue

Comment: So netcat is running fine it's your rabbitmq service that's having an issue as highlighted by your other question