# Unable to deploy RabbitMQ with gitlab-ci pipeline on google cloud?

Tags: spring-boot, docker, rabbitmq, gitlab, gitlab-ci

In springboot application, the configuration of `application-prod.yml` are :

```
spring:
  rabbitmq:
    host: rabbitmq
    port: 5672
    username: guest
    password:  guest
```

`gitlab-ci.yml` configuration are  :

```
services:
  - docker:dind
  - rabbitmq:management

variables:
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_USER: guest
  RABBITMQ_DEFAULT_PASS: guest
  AMQP_URL: 'amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672'

stages:
 - build

maven-foo-build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - cd foo
    - ./mvnw package -B -Dorg.slf4j.simpleLogger.log.org.apache.maven.cli.transfer.Slf4jMavenTransferListener=warn
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - foo/target/*.jar
```

I got the following exception on gitlab pipeline :

```
org.springframework.amqp.AmqpConnectException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.support.RabbitExceptionTranslator.convertRabbitAccessException(RabbitExceptionTranslator.java:62)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.AbstractConnectionFactory.createBareConnection(AbstractConnectionFactory.java:509)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.CachingConnectionFactory.createConnection(CachingConnectionFactory.java:702)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.connection.ConnectionFactoryUtils.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryUtils.java:214)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.doExecute(RabbitTemplate.java:2073)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2047)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitTemplate.execute(RabbitTemplate.java:2027)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin.getQueueProperties(RabbitAdmin.java:403)
    at org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.attemptDeclarations(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:1787)
```

I also tried to make a new stage and run on pipeline, before running build stage such as :

```
docker-image-test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - docker run -d --hostname rabbitmq --name rabbitmq  -p 5672:5672 rabbitmq:management
```

But got the same result , and unable to connect with RabbitMQ. And also follow the following link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43409988/how-to-use-rabbit-inside-a-gitlab-ci-yml-file) and got nothing.

Want to achieve to deploy RabbitMQ on production with gitlab CI/CD pipeline which currently we are using docker image `rabbitmq:management`. What am I going to miss there, any help would be grateful, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have found the solution , maybe it may help someone. Problem is with the connection factory in springboot application, which is unable to connect with docker image `rabbitmq:Management` when we go for live(prod). So we need to override the connection factory in our RabbitMQ Configurations.

Please find the source code here :

```
private static final String BROKER_URI = "amqp://guest:guest@rabbitmq:5672";
    @Bean
        public CachingConnectionFactory rabbitConnectionFactory(RabbitProperties config)
            throws Exception {
            CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory();
            connectionFactory.getRabbitConnectionFactory().setUri(BROKER_URI);
            return connectionFactory;
        }
```